# Can't connect to network locations in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, samba, shared-folders

Experiencing a very annoying issue where I can't connect to network shares, `smb` or `ssh` nothing works. in `Other Locations` > `Connect to Server` mouse pointer is always spinning & `connect` button stays grayed out.

[image]

Comment: ssh is not a share protocol. More info is required. Show what your ssh  command is.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @David thanks, but using `ssh` it's possible to connect. I've used it on other machines where I'm not experiencing this issue